# Group by date can't be sorted in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

This is the code:

Find how many users submitted any day. It has to be sorted from most recent to older.

```
import pandas as pd
a=pd.read_csv("dataset.txt")
b=a[['date_su','users']]
b.sort_values(['date_su'],ascending=False).groupby(['date_su','users'])['date_su'].count()
```

The result is this:

```
date_su                  users
1/8/2018                Jk_28_j                         1
                        KT1w_19_MN                     33
                        KT1w_19_USER                    9
                        KT1w_19_USER2                   5
                        KT1w_19_USER3                   7
                        KT1w_19_USER32                  1
                        KT1w_19_USER35                  8
                        KT1w_19_USER36                  7
                        KT1w_19_USER8                   8
                        KT1w_19_USER9                   6
                        MRS  sffdf                      1
                        SINBAo                          1
                        VIJJHxAFNI                      1
                        W7jj24693U242                   1
                        WW2pt710U455                    1
10/7/2018               idMIa9p0c                       1
                        KTw_19_MNG1                     4
                        KTw_19_MNG2                    18
                        KTw_19_USER1                    4
                        KTw_19_USER22                   8
                        KTw_19_USER32                   7
                        KTw_19_USER33                   5
                        KTw_19_USER34                   1
                        KTw_19_USER35                   3
10/8/2018               KTw_19_MNG1                     8
                        KTw_19_USER1                    5
                        KTw_19_USER2                    2
                        KTw_19_USER3                    3
```

The last line does not seem to sort by date but by users. Although it says `sort_values(['date_su']`.How to make it work as intended?

Comment: Can you show dataset.txt file? A few lines will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe need convert values to datetimes by parameter `parse_dates` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) and if necessary add also parameter `dayfirst=True`:

```
b=pd.read_csv("dataset.txt", 
              parse_dates=['date_su'], 
              usecols=['date_su','users'], 
              dayfirst=True)
```

And then sorting `MultiIndex`:

```
b.groupby(['date_su','users'])['date_su'].count().sort_index(level=[0,1], ascending=[False, True])
```

Or use `ascending=False` with parameter `sort=False` for avoid sorting in groupby:

```
b.sort_values(['date_su'],ascending=False).groupby(['date_su','users'], sort=False)['date_su'].count()
```

Comment: This solved it but it appears ascending and if I turn ascending to False it doesn't change?

Comment: @user10319541 - In sample data `10/7/2018` is `10 July 2018` and should be first?

Comment: It should show first the most recent which is 10/08/2018.Now is july in the first line.